# how to add normal script code to view.ctp in CakePHP 2.2.4

Tags: jquery, cakephp

enter code hereI want to insert this code to my .ctp file

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('open').click(function(){
            $('#pop_background').fadeIn();
            $('#pop_box').fadeIn();
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

it should work with this

`<a href="#" id="open">Open popup box</a>`
I have created the relevant CSS files and div for 'pop_background' and 'pop_box'.
Now it should be appeared when I click the 'open popup box' link.
how can I do this in CakePHP

Comment: You can just paste somewhere on the (e.g. at the end of the) ctp file, in this case you can look at ctp file as a usual html/php file

Comment: btw, your event is for clicking on `open` tag, I assume you wanted to have open class - `.open` or open id `#open`

Comment: Thank you dav for helping me to improve my question. It was very helpful since I am new to here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check if you have loaded jQuery in your layout (include it in the head of the document if you want it to work like this)
2. It's `$('#open')`, not `$('open')`. Use jQuery selectors just like in css.

Comment: Thank you for giving me the support, I added 
`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>` in top of file. Then it was done.